# Kill QProcess that was stopped and resumed

Tags: qt, unix, signals

I have a QProcess which has to be paused and resumed. I use

```
kill(pid_t(process->pid()), SIGSTOP);
```

and

```
kill(pid_t(process->pid()), SIGCONT);
```

to pause/resume the process.

However, once it is done, the process can no longer be terminated, even by `QProcess:kill()`. Basically, no `QProcess::waitForFinished()` ever succeeds and the process becomes zombie.

Does someone know the reason for this and is there any solution?

Note: I tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997332/waiting-for-qprocess-to-finish-or-duration-to-exceed/15004222#15004222) and it doesn't help. I am doing this on Mac, but googling suggest the problem also happens on Linux.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.  As it is I'm not sure why a stopped/started process should behave any differently from any other.

Comment: I added [an example](https://codepad.co/snippet/xESMFqOy). It seems one paused/resumed process doesn't cause enough problems, but once you include the second, things go wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it detaches in which case you need to do a system scan for the process.

Comment: I can still send/receive messages to/from the process - would it be possible if the process was detached? And the process doesn't keep running, it becomes zombie. Also, is there any reason the process will be detached by a signal?

Comment: I created a small bash script (`while true; do sleep(2); done`). With this, the example you provided works for me in both variants (w and w/o process 2). Immediately after the `m_process->kill()` the `m_process->waitForFinished(1000)` returns and the program prints `0: exited`. There is no zombie process left. Maybe the problem is with your slave process?

Comment: That is basically the answer [I linked in my description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997332/waiting-for-qprocess-to-finish-or-duration-to-exceed/15004222#15004222). Alas, it doesn't work for me. Sometimes changing the order or closing helps, but what I don't get is why it fails in any case. I doubt the problem is with process itself - it quits as required, the app is stuck in QProcess, as debugging shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, lots of things can happen when SIGSTOP and a subsequent SIGCONT are sent to a process.  Related processes (child or parent processes for instance) are not co-stopped when stopping a process.  This may lead to weird anomalies like the breaking of pipes or delays which lead to timeouts.  So in general, these signals aren't well supported.  Only for very simple architectures (no forking, no child processes, etc.) they should work.  Also, since a process can react upon SIGCONT, any framework (like QT) might do so and re-initialize some of its facilities.  This makes also sense, of course, because after being stopped, some things might have changed which otherwise might have been noticed at the time of their change.

Unfortunately, the case is so rare and encompasses so many different aspects that this is normally not completely test-covered, so bugs are rather likely, compared to other parts of the same library.  I would assume that you just found an issue in the QT code or that the framework just doesn't support these signals.  Do you have any documentation which states that it should?

Steps you could do now:

- Search for an already filed bug report in the bug tracking system of the related library.
- Create an [mcve](/help/mcve) showing the issue.
- If nothing is filed, file a bug report ;-)

But I wouldn't expect the maintainers of the libraries to react very quickly, if at all.  As I said, SIGSTOP and SIGCONT often aren't supported on more complex scenarios.  Their implications just are too complex.